# My mobile menu navbar doesn't close, it only opens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

The button does open the navbar but when I click back it doesn't close

```
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>        
      </button>**
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="collapse">&times;</button>
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#inicio">INICIO</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#acercade">ACERCA DE</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#servicios">SERVICIOS</a>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#ubicacion">UBICACIÓN</a>
          </li>
             <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contacto">CONTACTO</a>
          </li>
              <li class="nav-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in">
            <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

I've tried many ways to fix but I have no clue

Comment: Yes, I am, but for some reason my code doesn't work properly

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? Can you provide a snippet or [pen](http://codepen.io/pen/)?

Comment: Bootstrap v4.0.0